# Notes export all as PDF

Tags: applescript

Ability to export all Notes in macOS Notes.app as PDFs.

execution error: Notes got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)

Multiple scripts, latest below.

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    repeat with theFolder in every folder
        repeat with theNote in every note of theFolder
            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "Notes"
                    set dockPrefs to dock preferences
                    set appearancePrefs to appearance preferences
                    delay 1
                    display dialog "Foo"
                    tell menu bar 1 of process "Notes"
                        click menu bar item "File"
                        click menu item "Export as PDF..." of menu "File" of menu bar of process "Notes"
                    end tell
                    click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window "Notes" of process "Notes"
                    delay 1
                    key code 125
                end tell
            end tell
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

execution error: Notes got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in there:

1. You are already targeting the Notes process, so including that in
   the click statements is adding another process target - use one or the other, but if you are
   doing a lot of menu clicks you might look at using a general
   purpose handler;
2. The export menu item uses an *ellipse* (a single character), not three
   periods;
3. By placing a `display dialog` statement in the System Events tell statement, you are moving the focus away from the application.

Also note that the text field is selected and the save button is the default in the sheet, so you can use keystrokes instead of trying to click UI elements.  A cleaned up example (tested in Mojave) would look something like:

```
tell application "Notes"
    launch -- seems to work better than 'activate'
    repeat with aFolder in folders
        repeat with aNote in notes of aFolder
            set noteName to (name of aNote)
            try -- keep the name a reasonable length
                set noteName to text 1 thru 20 of noteName
            end try
            tell (current date) to set timeStamp to text 2 thru -1 of (get (1000000 + (its hours) * 10000 + (its minutes) * 100 + (its seconds)) as text) -- hhmmss

            tell application "System Events"
                #display dialog noteName -- testing?
                tell process "Notes"
                    set frontmost to true -- retarget the Notes app
                    delay 0.5
                    click menu item "Export as PDF…" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
                    repeat until exists sheet 1 of window 1 -- wait for the sheet
                        delay 0.02
                    end repeat
                end tell
                keystroke noteName & "_" & timeStamp -- update the name, trying to avoid duplicates
                delay 0.5
                keystroke return -- dismiss the sheet
                delay 0.5
                key code 125
            end tell

        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks on Catalina I get the following error when it runs.

execution error: Notes got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)

Comment: _Where_ is it failing?  The delay timing around the sheet was a bit picky in my tests, but it also works on my Catalina system (at least with the few notes I have).

Comment: It fires Notes.. But fails straight away, zero dumped.
I've changed all Delays to 1.5 and no difference ?
I read somewhere catalina made some changes which causes the -10000 issue ?